# Transfer Learning of VGG16 on colab lead to a OOM

Tags: deep-learning, conv-neural-network, google-colaboratory

I am using colab 25Ram for implementing Human action recognition, all my models always crashed my session because i used all the memory (also if they are not so big).

Im trying now to use transfer learning of VGG16, i began with the real model and just added a TimeDistributed of my model to match it with my data and a Dense layer to check if that work, and my colab session also crashed.

```
video = Input(shape=(350, 288, 384, 3))
cnn_base = VGG16(input_shape=(288, 384, 3), weights="imagenet", include_top=False)
cnn_out = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(cnn_base.output)
cnn = Model(inputs=cnn_base.input, outputs=cnn_out)
cnn.trainable = False
x = TimeDistributed(cnn)(video)
x = Dense(1, activation="sigmoid")(x)
model = Model([video], x)
model.summary()

model.compile(optimizer='SGD', loss='binary_crossentropy',metrics=["accuracy"])
model.fit(x=X, y=y, batch_size=2, epochs=1)
```

All advices will help me, im already 2 weeks stuck with OOM problems on colab.Thanks

Comment: You are not going to get anywhere with this setup, you want to process 350 timesteps with a very large network (VGG has over 100M  weights), there is no GPU that has enough RAM to do this processing, you probably want to reduce RAM usage with less timesteps, smaller networks, and smaller image sizes.

Comment: thanks, wich network do u advice me to choose if not VGG?